# Redis broken pipe error when running in istio mesh

Tags: redis, istio

Connection to redis works when I run the client in Kubernetes cluster but I get 'broken pipe' error when ran inside a istio mesh

```
redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
        at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.flush(Connection.java:334)
        at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getIntegerReply(Connection.java:263)
        at redis.clients.jedis.Jedis.exists(Jedis.java:179)
        at com.swift.ems.microservices.CreateSessionServer$AuthServiceImpl.createSessionAuth(CreateSessionServer.java:59)
        at com.swift.ems.microservices.AuthServiceGrpc$MethodHandlers.invoke(AuthServiceGrpc.java:204)
        at io.grpc.stub.ServerCalls$UnaryServerCallHandler$UnaryServerCallListener.onHalfClose(ServerCalls.java:171)
        at io.grpc.internal.ServerCallImpl$ServerStreamListenerImpl.halfClosed(ServerCallImpl.java:283)
        at io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl$JumpToApplicationThreadServerStreamListener$1HalfClosed.runInContext(ServerImpl.java:707)
        at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
        at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
        at redis.clients.util.RedisOutputStream.flushBuffer(RedisOutputStream.java:52)
        at redis.clients.util.RedisOutputStream.flush(RedisOutputStream.java:216)
        at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.flush(Connection.java:331)
        ... 12 more
ERROR ConnectingSep 12, 2018 9:04:19 PM io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor run
SEVERE: Exception while executing runnable io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl$JumpToApplicationThreadServerStreamListener$1HalfClosed@525a867b
redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
        at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.flush(Connection.java:334)
        at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getBinaryBulkReply(Connection.java:257)
        at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getBulkReply(Connection.java:248)
        at redis.clients.jedis.Jedis.get(Jedis.java:153)
        at com.swift.ems.redis.SessionHandler.getStatus(SessionHandler.java:61)
        at com.swift.ems.microservices.CreateSessionServer$AuthServiceImpl.createSessionAuth(CreateSessionServer.java:74)
        at com.swift.ems.microservices.AuthServiceGrpc$MethodHandlers.invoke(AuthServiceGrpc.java:204)
        at io.grpc.stub.ServerCalls$UnaryServerCallHandler$UnaryServerCallListener.onHalfClose(ServerCalls.java:171)
        at io.grpc.internal.ServerCallImpl$ServerStreamListenerImpl.halfClosed(ServerCallImpl.java:283)
        at io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl$JumpToApplicationThreadServerStreamListener$1HalfClosed.runInContext(ServerImpl.java:707)
        at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
        at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
        at redis.clients.util.RedisOutputStream.flushBuffer(RedisOutputStream.java:52)
        at redis.clients.util.RedisOutputStream.flush(RedisOutputStream.java:216)
        at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.flush(Connection.java:331)
        ... 14 more
```

I believe it needs to give more time for connecting but not sure, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Istio was blocking the connection to redis so created a service entry and it worked!
https://istio.io/blog/2018/egress-tcp/#mesh-external-service-entry-for-an-external-mysql-instance